# :version shows "Dependencies: python27.dll, which is not on my computer

Tags: python-3.4

I downloaded Vim 7.3 and installed it on my Windows7 64 bit system. I coded a simple python 3.4 program and tried to run it without success using the :!python COMMAND. When I checked version, bottom of output said:

```
Dependency: python27.dll, python33.dll, x64-msvcrt-ruby200.dll, lva52.dll, libintl.dll, lidiconv.dll, iconv.dll.
```

When I checked, python27.dll is not found on my system at all, python33.dll is in a directory for a program called "Autodesk 123D Design". I didn't check for the others yet. Can someone explain if these are required and if so, where they go? I have no idea why they would not have downloaded with the program during install.

Answer (score 0):

They are used for writing vim plugins in Python. They are not required for normal operation.

They are also unrelated to your problem; check the value of `%PATH%` to see if `python.exe` is accessible.